# Ad Mob firebase less impressions than sessions

Tags: android, firebase, admob, banner-ads

i developed an app 20 days ago and added Admob Ads Natives with Firebase. I encountered a strange situation with Firebase statistics. In the last 30 days I had 31 sessions but only 2 impressions. The code runs well, I see all the banner inside the app and no exceptions I see in logcat so it should be ok.
Someone had a similar problem? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Something goes wrong with Firebase console because inside [AdMob console](http://apps.admob.com) i see all impressions.